# javascript split of Date

Tags: javascript

I have this Date Format `var date = 'Jun 2, 2011 3:05:14 PM';`

I want to split it in such a way that i should get only Hours from this

Could anybody please help me .

Thank you .

Answer (score 5):

Create a `Date` first, then get the hours:

```
var date = new Date('Jun 2, 2011 3:05:14 PM');
var hours = date.getHours();
```

If you want `3` instead of `15`, add this:

```
if (hours > 12) hours -= 12;
```

Midnight will return `0`.  To get `12` instead, add this:

```
if (hours == 0) hours = 12;
```

Comment: Thank you very much , cant i use in this way var hrs = date.split(' ')[0].split(' ')[0]; // To get only Date

Comment: Some times i need to get the whole hours from 0 to 24 , for 1 Day

Comment: @Pavan - To get the date: `var dayOfMonth = date.getDate()`.  `getHours()` returns a number from 0 to 23 (0 for 12 AM).  So, you can choose whether to use the number returned, or parse it to 12 hr format.

Answer (score 2):

Use the string to create a date object which grants you methods to traverse it:

```
new Date('Jun 2, 2011 3:05:14 PM').getHours();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var date = 'Jun 2, 2011 3:05:14 PM';
var hours = new Date(date).getHours();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = 'Jun 2, 2011 3:05:14 PM', 
hours=date.split(/\W+/)[3];
```

Without a time zone, dates are not portable.